# Passing parameters between angular objects

Tags: angularjs

I have the following controller:

```
appControllers.controller('orgCtrl', function ($scope, orgService) {
  ...
  $scope.orgDel = function (org) {
    orgService.delete(org, function () {
      orgService.getList(function (err, list) {
        if (err)
          console.log('Error: ', err);
        else
          $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.list = list;
          });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

And the following link on my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="org in list">
    <div ng-controller="OrgCtrl">
        <a href="#" ng-click="orgDel(org.name)">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add an 'Are you sure?' modal. So I changed the link to:

```
<a href="#" id="warning">Delete</a>
```

Here's the modal (jade code):

```
#warning.modal.fade
    .modal-dialog
      .modal-content
        .modal-header
          button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-hidden='true') ×
          h4.modal-title Warning
        .modal-body
          p Are you sure you want to delete this organization?
        .modal-footer
          .spinner
            .cube1
            .cube2
          button.btn.btn-default(type='button', data-dismiss='modal') Close
          button.btn.btn-primary(type='button', ng-click="delOrg()") Delete
```

And I'm launching the modal using jQuery. But how can I implement the `orgDel` in the opened modal now that out of the `ng-repeat` scope? I need to somehow pass the `org.name` parameter to the modal but not sure how

Comment: where is `modal` code, please post.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove jQuery and use <kbd>[UI Bootstrap for Angular](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)</kbd> modal.

And this is a demo where we pass some data to model: <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l3vuOBG01EXJnSn96B4S?p=preview)</kbd>

Generally modal has his own controller (or lets say scope).

By invoking `resolve` we pass `items` list to modal:

```
resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
```

Also you can pass the copy of object:

```
resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return angualr.copy($scope.items);
        }
```

Comment: I second UI Bootstrap, but you might only need a popover. I adapted this for my needs: http://wegnerdesign.com/blog/angular-js-directive-tutorial-on-attribute-bootstrap-confirm-button/